# Coverting POST from requests to GAE urlfetch

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, python-requests

I am doing a payment with PayPal. Here is how it works properly with `requests`:

```
res = requests.post(get_payment_info_url, headers=headers, data=params)
res_data = res.json()
```

But then when I try and do the same request with the `urlfetch`, it gives me an error (a 200 response from PayPal, but the payment Fails):

```
res = urlfetch.fetch(url=make_payment_url, payload=params, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=headers)
res_data = json.loads(res)

{u'responseEnvelope': {u'timestamp': u'2015-02-15T23:21:52.729-08:00', u'ack': u'Failure', u'build': u'15089777', u'correlationId': u'e202988541fde'}, 
u'error': [{u'domain': u'PLATFORM', u'message': u'Invalid request: {0}', u'severity': u'Error', u'subdomain': 
u'Application', u'category': u'Application', u'errorId': u'580001'}]}
```

It seems that maybe Google is stripping headers or something? How would I then make this request if Google is doing that?

Finally, is there any reason to use `urlfetch` over `requests` (which I've imported locally into my GAE project? Requests seems so much easier and 'friendly' to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, the payload needs to be urlencoded. Here is what worked:

```
res2 = urlfetch.fetch(
                 url,
                 headers=headers,
                 method='POST',
                 payload=urllib.urlencode(params)
               )
res2_data = json.loads(res2.content)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK I managed to patch this lib easily to work with GAE as described here:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/66

Requests works on GAE, but only version 2.3.0(!)

On Google Appengine (version 1.9.17) [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) *version 2.3.0 (only!)* works **IN PRODUCTION** (but not on SDK) if you have billing enabled, which enables sockets support.

requests on the Appengine SDK fails with all https:// requests:

```
  ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

requests version 2.4.1 fails with:

```
  File "distlib/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
  ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

requests version 2.5.1 fails with:

```
  File "distlib/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
  ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

Info on sockets support: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/