# Python post data to url

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, http-post

I'm using App Engine and I'm trying to post data to a URL similar to this :

```
https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/<widget-id>
```

I've tried the following code:

```
data = {
            "api_key" : api_key,
            "data" : {
                      "item" : [
                                {
                                 "value" : chatamount
                                 }
                                ]
                      }
            }

    encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(data)
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(pushurl)
    conn.request("POST", "", encoded_args)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    logging.info(response.status)
    conn.close()
```

However, the logging returns a 400 error. Does anyone know how to perform a simple data POST using Python and App Engine?

Comment: What does the actual response say? It should provide more information about what went wrong

Comment: I've generally used the `urlfetch` service...  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536376/coverting-post-from-requests-to-gae-urlfetch

Comment: @ Suever 4, when I log response.reason it says: 400: Bad Request

Comment: @mgilson thanks I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The error 400 was caused because the data was url encoded which it shouldn't be. By changing

```
conn.request("POST", "", encoded_args)
```

to

```
conn.request("POST", "", json.dumps(data))
```

the problem was solved.

Thanks for the help!